# xargs touch followed by second command

Tags: bash, xargs

I am randomly selecting files from a directory that I want to process, and I want to apply the touch command to them so that I know the last one that's been visualized, then apply the visualization program. Something like this:

```
while [ 1 ]; do ls | shuf | xargs "touch & vizprogram"; done
```

Since I am manually inspecting these datasets, I want to be able to "Esc" from the loop at any point, so that I interrupt the vizprogram and go through the loop again. Then when I find a file I want to follow on, I want to Ctrl+C and do an `ls -rt | tail -n 1` to have the name of the last file I've used. I tried this with a for or while loop instead of `xargs`, but then I cannot do "Esc" on the main loop.

Any ideas how to do the "touch then vizprogram" within xargs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `vizprogram` returns true if exited with ESC and false if exited with Ctrl-C you can do:

```
while ls | shuf | parallel --halt 2 -j1 "touch {}; vizprogram {}"; do true; done
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 2):

Create a shell script such as the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    touch "$1"
    vizprogram "$1"
    shift
done
```

Then have `xargs` execute it:

```
echo "file file2 file3" | xargs /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *cannot do "Esc"*. `Ctrl-C` works just fine with my answer. Let me know if I missed the point, I'll delete it then.

Comment: I use "Esc" to interrupt the vizprogram for files I don't want to follow on, but then do Ctrl+C to stop the loop when I find a file I want to closely inspect. I would like to have this file marked somehow, and doing a touch on it would give me its file name by being the one with the latest timestamp.

Comment: @avilella Unless you edit `vizprogram`, there is no way to do this other than what I suggest. Your `xargs` method runs `vizprogram` with all files as arguments, in order -- you cannot interleave something else with a single program call. Individual invocations for every file, similar to what I suggest, or editing `vizprogram` are your only options I'm afraid (although I look forward to being proved wrong).